# How to achieve callback functionality on saving a record when in auto save mode in google appmaker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a model which is in autosave mode. When the user clicks on a button below code is executed.
 I want the status to change and get saved and then it should execute the refresh function as the refresh functionality is dependent on the status value. But with the below code refresh function is getting executed before the new status is getting saved.

```
       widget.datasource.item.status='inside';
       refreshPanelWithColor();
```

What I really want to do is this to have the callback functionality but I can't use the saveChanges as it's only for manual save mode.

```
      widget.datasource.item.status='inside';
     widget.datasource.saveChanges(function() {
     refreshPanelWithColor();
     });
```

How to achieve callback functionality here without switching to manual save mode?

Comment: This functionality does not exist at the moment. I filed a feature request for it here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129996396. Only option at the moment would be to use JS timeOut function, but even in that case you have to allow sufficient time to hopefully have the client update after the server was contacted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As how Markus Explains in his comment, this functionality is not available at the moment. You can of course use another solution which is using server scripting and reloading the datasource item. In order to achieve that, your client script should look similar to this:

```
var recordKey = widget.datasource.item._key;
var status = "inside";
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){
    widget.datasource.item._reload(function(){
        refreshPanelWithColor();
    });
}).withFailureHandler(function(err){
    console.err(err.toString());
}).updateDesiredRecord(recordKey, status);
```

And of course, you need to implement your server script being called from the client. It should look something like this:

```
function updateDesiredRecord(recordKey, status){
    var record = app.models.MYMODEL.getRecord(recordKey);
    record.status = status;
    app.saveRecords([record]);
}
```

I'm not sure what your `refreshPanelWithColor()` function does but I hope you get an idea of what this solution intends to.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to bind your function to datasource on after save event.